# error while adding Account details in manytomany relationship with Customer in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-many

I am using **@manytomany** relationship in spring boot between **Account** and **Customer** class.
Account class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int accountNumber;
    public String accountType;
    public int balance;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
//skipped constructors, getters and setters and tostring method
```

Customer class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int customerId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Account> accounts;
}
//skipped constructors, getters and setters and tostring method
```

I am trying to send a post request as shown below which fetches the customer present in Customer table with the given id, and created new account for it as given in the json body in post request.
[image]

Below is the handler method which handles the post request as shown in the screenshot attached above.

```java
@PostMapping("/customers/{id}/accounts")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAccountForCustomer(@RequestBody Account account, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        account.setAccountNumber(0);
        System.out.println(account);
        // fetching customer object based on given customer id
        Customer fetchCustomerByID = this.customerServices.fetchAccountByID(id);

        if (fetchCustomerByID == null) {
            System.out.println("Customer doesn't exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Customer doesn't exit", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fetchCustomerByID);
            System.out.println("Customer exists. Creating account!!");

            List<Account> listOfAccounts = fetchCustomerByID.getAccounts();
            listOfAccounts.add(account);
            fetchCustomerByID.setAccounts(listOfAccounts);// adding given account to fetched customer
            System.out.println("newly created customer" + fetchCustomerByID);
            Customer ac = this.customerServices.addAccount(fetchCustomerByID);
            
            // saving fetched customer back to database with updated customer details

            // adding fetched customer to newly created account from given json
            List<Customer> listOfCustomers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            listOfCustomers.add(fetchCustomerByID);
            account.setCustomers(listOfCustomers);// creating customer list for given account
            System.out.println("newly created account" + account);
            Account addAccount = this.accountServices.addAccount(account);// saving new account to database
            

            return new ResponseEntity<String>("account created for customer", HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
```

CustomerServices addAccount method-

```java
 // add an account
    public Customer addAccount(Customer account) {
        Customer acc = this.customerRepository.save(account);
        return acc;
    }
```

AccountServices addAccount method-

```java
  // add an account
    public Account addAccount(Account account) {
        Account acc = this.accountRepository.save(account);
        return acc;
    }
```

AccountRepository and CustomerRepository are interfaces which extends CrudRepository interface to do database related operations.

Question - When I run the shown post request, everything is working fine. Details are also added in database as shown below -
[image]

But when I try to fetch account (using get request with id) which is added by the above post request, it is showing error.(For account details which were not added by the post request above are getting fetched without any error)
Error is -

```java
 at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Account.toString(Account.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Customer.toString(Customer.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Account.toString(Account.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Customer.toString(Customer.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Account.toString(Account.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Customer.toString(Customer.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Account.toString(Account.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Customer.toString(Customer.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367) ~[na:na]
```

Adding stacktrace error shown in HTTP response -

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:112)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:125)\r\n\tat ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Account.toString(Account.java:68)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167)\r\n\tat ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Customer.toString(Customer.java:80)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3367)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:167)\r\n\tat ma20099449.foundation.bank.ma20099449_bank.Entities.Account.toStrin
```

Adding get method to fetch account details for id

```java
  // get method to fetch single record based on id given in request
    @GetMapping("/accounts/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> getAccountById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        Account fetchAccountByID = this.accountServices.fetchAccountByID(id);
        if (fetchAccountByID == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(fetchAccountByID, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            // System.out.println(fetchAccountByID);
            System.out.println(fetchAccountByID != null ? fetchAccountByID : "null");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(fetchAccountByID, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

I am adding toString method of Account Class

```java
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + " accountNumber='" + getAccountNumber() + "'" + ", accountType='" + getAccountType() + "'"
                + ", balance='" + getBalance() + "'" + ", customers='" + getCustomers() + "'" + "}";
    }
```

Comment: Please share one line more on the top of your stacktrace so we can see what type of exception you get.

Comment: Hi @KajHejer, I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: At least the "toString" has a cyclic problem! - I recommend not to do something like (Accounts.toString):  `"customer="+customer.toString`, instead use `"customer="+(this.customer!=null ? customer.getLastName : "null")` -- when you fix this, then you will get hopefully a better exception about the real causing problem.

Comment: Hi @Ralph, I have changed my approach to call toString method to print object of Account class. I have also added the changed getAccountByID() to fetch account based on an id but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Mayank Kumar Thakur: I have added an answer with the recommended code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not the root cause of the problem, but your `Account.toString()` method  causes in infitite loop: `Account.toString()` invoke `Customer.toString()` and `Customer.toString()` invoke `Account.toString()` for the same account.

You need to stop that loop! I would recommend not to "print" the full customer when  `Account.toString` is invoked. Instead I would "print" only some identifying details.

```
public class Customer {
   public String toStringShort() {
       return "{id=" + id 
              + ", firstName='"+ firstName 
              + "', lastName='"+ lastName + "'}"
   }
}
```

```
public class Account {
   ...
   public String toString() {
       final String shortCustomersToString;
       if(this.customers != null) 
          shortCustomersToString = this.customers.stream()
             .map(Customer::toStringShort)
             .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
       else
          shortCustomersToString = null;

       return "{" + " accountNumber='" + getAccountNumber() + "'" 
                  + ", accountType='" + getAccountType() + "'" 
                  + ", balance='" + getBalance() + "'" 
                  + ", customers=" + shortCustomersToString + "}";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `System.out.println(fetchAccountByID!= null ? fetchAccountByID : "null");` from `getAccountById()` method in your controller class. In `System.out.println` you are trying to print Account details that time calling to `toString()` method in Account class. So you better remove `System.out.println` or else add proper `toString` method in Account class.

As requested Please find the customized `toString()` methods in Account & Customer Classes.

- Account Class `toString()` method

```
@Override 
public String toString()
{
    return "Account{" +
        "accountNumber=" + accountNumber +
        ", accountType='" + accountType + '\'' +
        ", balance=" + balance +
        ", customers=" + customers +
        '}';
}
```

- Customer  Class `toString()` method

```
@Override 
public String toString()
{
    return "Customer{" +
        "customerId=" + customerId +
        ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
        ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
        ", email='" + email + '\'' +
        '}';
}
```

Comment: Hi @SGR, I removed System.out.println() method from my getAccountById() just as you said. And now, it is working fine. I am adding my Account class toString method in question. Could please help me to write the proper toString method?

Comment: Hi @MayankKumarThakur sorry for the delay on replying to you. As Ralph mentioned you can customized and override toString() method with required fields as you want here updated my answer with your request

Comment: @MayankKumarThakur let me know if you have any questions